# Adding error message to python add-in?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-addin

I want to add an alert message to my python add-in(which will be like, when I click a button it will summon a warning message ). But I tried error message functions like : AddError, AddWarning and they just dont do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/the-pythonaddins-module.htm), you have to use the `pythonaddins.MessageBox()`.

`pythonaddins.MessageBox("your error message", "Error", 0)`